# What is the practical usage of interface not directly implemented in class?

Tags: c#, oop

I think I have a very naive question here that I didn't knew before that it was even possible. Forgive me if my title question is a bit vague because I don't even know how to describe it. Here is the code that looks weird to me.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void ImplementMe();
}

public class StandAlone
{
    public void ImplementMe()
    {
        Console.writeline("It works!");
    }
}

public class SubClass : StandAlone, IMyInterface
{
    // no need to implement IMyInterface here but it still work!!!
}

IMyInterface myInterface = new SubClass();
myInterface.ImplementMe();   // Output : "It works!"
```

I just want to know the following :

- What is the right term to describe this approach?
- What is the practical benefit of this kind of approach?
- What kind of problem it tries to solve? or What scenario this will be applicable?

Comment: Odd - normally I'd expect to see the interface implemented on the base class. I think this is just a coding error.

Comment: Yes, very Odd!! But it was existing in our code base!! I'm so very naive of that approach and I feel like I don't under OOP and Interface??? :(

Comment: I guess the reason for this is that `StandAlone` existed first. Then there was the need to extend the code so that multiple implementations of `ImplementMe` were possible, so the decision was to generalize this into an interface. Instead of changing `StandAlone` (thus maybe breaking existing code), a subclass `SubClass` now conforms to the interface. Of course you'd probably not choose this approach if you designed your software from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first case that comes to my mind - when you don't own source code of `StandAlone` class, but later you decided to introduce interface which describes behavior of `StandAlone` class. E.g. for unit-testing (it's not best practice to mock code which you don't own, but sometimes it might be helpful) or you want to provide alternative implementation of `StandAlone` behavior in some cases. So either you have no options for unit-testing such code:

```
public class SUT
{
    private readonly StandAlone dependency;

    public SUT(StandAlone dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    // ...
}
```

But if you'll introduce interface, you can actually switch to dependency from `IMyInterface` instead of `StandAlone`. And provide `SubClass` as implementation of interface with zero efforts.

```
public class SUT
{
    private readonly IMyInterface dependency;

    public SUT(IMyInterface dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining but we actually own the source code. does it mean code smell?

Comment: @jtabuloc if you are free to modify base class and ship new assembly, then I believe someone just was scared of modifying base class. I don't see any good reasons for such pattern

Comment: I agree with you! Probably the impact of refactoring in base class could hurt

Answer (score 3):

But `SubClass` *does* implement the `IMyInterface` - it has all the required public members with the right signatures. There's no specific terminology since there's nothing weird about it.

In fact, some languages take this even further, and allow you to *cast* any object to an interface, as long as the class has the right members (and in yet more flexible languages, even if it doesn't).

The main benefit is again the same as any other way to use interfaces - it allows you to abstract the implementation away from the interface. It's just a shortcut to having to do an explicit interface implementation, something like:

```
class SubClass : BaseClass, IInterface
{
  void IInterface.MyMethod()
  {
    base.MyMethod();
  }
}
```

You might think that you could just implement the interface in the base class, but there's plenty of reasons why you wouldn't:

- You don't want to maintain a public interface for the base class, it's just an internal class that shouldn't be exposed outside.
- You don't have a way to change the base class to include the interface, so if you want to keep an inheritance chain, you must subclass and add the interface to the subclass.
- The inferface contains some members that aren't contained in the `BaseClass`.

You'll probably find a couple more reasons if you try.

But the main point is: why not? You need a *reason* to do something (expand the definition of the base class instead of just the subclass). Adding abstraction everywhere along your codebase is rarely beneficial - you're trying to find a good trade-off between clarity of intent and clarity of implementation. An interface on a base class might help or hinder that.

Comment: Good point that interface might have more members than base class. Though not sure about implementing public interface by internal class. Implementation will stay internal if you add subclass here

Comment: Thanks @Luaan! it may take a while for me before I can fully grasp your answer and implement this kind of approach but I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2):

One legitimate use of this pattern (Outside of simply the original programmer should have put the interface on the base class) could be that `Standalone` is in a 3rd party (or inaccessible) assembly, and `IMyInterface` was written in your own code to provide a Facade.

Consider this;

- Your app wants to provide some functionality. You define an interface with method `ImplementMe`.
- `Standalone` is in ThirdParty.dll and provides this exact method name (Perhaps you modelled your interface on that method name on purpose)
- You subclass `Standalone` within your own code in order to implement your functionality.
- Maybe you have a second way of implementing `ImplementMe` for which you have your onw class implementing your own interface. (`public class MyOwnImplemetation : IMyInterface {... }`)

You could then use DI to instantiate the correct implementation of `StandAlone` or `MyOwnImplemetation` but treat them both as `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but like what I commented out in Sergey answer, we actually own the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Not all classes are direct implementations of interfaces.

For example, let's put a good sample based on a simple class inheritance:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
}
```

Now, let's imagine that we need to store uniquely-identifiable objects in some common store where we don't care about the entities' types but just about **they're uniquely-identifiable**.

BTW, we consider that *persons* shouldn't be stored within such store, because they're not valid entities within our organization but they're just there to improve code reusability and *don't repeat ourselves*.

So we define an interface like this:

```
public interface ICanBeUniquelyIdentifiable
{
     Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

...and we don't implement it on `Person` but we do so on `Employee`:

```
// Now an employee is an actual object that can be uniquely identifiable,
// and this isn't true because Person has an Id property, but because
// Employee fulfills the contract!
public class Employee : Person, ICanBeUniquelyIdentifiable
{
}
```

### Background

I would say that your reasoning should be that **you implement interfaces where they really matter to be implemented**, and reusability shouldn't be the key point when implementing interfaces.

Actually, you should implement interfaces on objects which should be accepted on some API and you just need a subset of the full type of a given object.